# Can't use fit() in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, web-mapping

I am trying to display a map of the USA in OpenLayers, and am trying to fit it to a layer. I tried `map.getView().fit(Usa.getSource().getExtent());` but that didn't do anything. I thought that maybe the extent was the same as the map for some reason, but no other lines of code would run after that line of code. I am not experienced with openlayers, and javascript is not my first language, so I assume the problem is something silly that I have overlooked.  Here is all of the code:

```
const Usa = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: '/data/Usa.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON(),

  }),
  
});
const map = new Map ({
  view: new View({
    
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 1,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
  }),
  target: 'map-container',
  
});
map.addLayer(Usa);
map.getView().fit(Usa.getSource().getExtent());
```

Comment: You need to wait until the source has loaded `Usa.getSource().on('featuresloadend', () => { map.getView().fit(Usa.getSource().getExtent()); });`

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! I'm going to answer and reference to your comment.

Comment: Also, is there any mention of why this is necessary on the API docs?

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike commented: "You need to wait until the source has loaded `Usa.getSource().on('featuresloadend', () => { map.getView().fit(Usa.getSource().getExtent()); });`".